# Column of words to a list of words in quotation marks with commas separating them

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this column of words:

```
Suzuki music
Chinese music
Conservatory
Blue grass
Rock n roll
Rhythm
Composition
Contra
Instruments
```

into this format:

```
"suzuki music", "chinese music", "conservatory music", "blue grass", "rock n roll", "rhythm"...
```

This is what I've tried:

```
stuff = [
        Suzuki music
        Chinese music
        Conservatory
        Blue grass
        Rock n roll
        Rhythm
        Composition
        Contra
        Instruments 
]

for line in stuff:
    list.append("'" + line + "',")
```

But I get this error:

File "/private/var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/artsplus_format_script-393966065.996.py", line 2
    stuff = [
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this in the `input.txt`:

```
Suzuki music
Chinese music
Conservatory
Blue grass
Rock n roll
Rhythm
Composition
Contra
Instruments
```

Then this code:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
   print ", ".join(['"%s"' % row.lower() for row in f.read().splitlines()])
```

will print you:

```
"Suzuki music", "Chinese music", "Conservatory", "Blue grass", "Rock n roll", "Rhythm", "Composition", "Contra", "Instruments"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`string.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) function

For your specific example the code would look like:

```
  ', '.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"',stuff))
```

Using [the `map` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) along with the lambda function effectively puts quotes around every element in your `stuff` collection.